# How to create views of nodes and all revisions in?

Tags: views, nodes

As it is obvious form the title I am want to create a views which has all contents of a given type and all its revisions under it.

I tried these ways but none of theme gave all I need:

1. Create a views from contents with relation to revision `NID`.
   It just give the last revision.
2. Create a views from contents with relation to revision `ID`.
   It has no difference with the previous one.
3. Create a views from content revision.
   Again just the latest version appeared.

So what will be solution to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Simple step by step instruction:

1. Try to create view by content revisions.
2. Remove relation to actual revision (added by default).
3. Also be sure that filter by published node isn't enabled.
4. It should work.

Comment: if I remove actual revision relation, how can I have fields of content?

Comment: They should be available for each revision but not only for actual revision

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it by using a patch. [This patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/views-1754354-14.patch) was useful for a number of users with similar issues. Also check this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37084/list-all-revison-users-on-a-node) out to see if it can help you out.